# Best way to export/import MS Sql 2008 Geography data

Tags: sql-server-2008, export, geography, bcp

#### (ANSWER) How to export some Geography data from a Microsoft Sql Server 2008.

You'll need to use the command line argument BCP to dump the data in it's original (native) format to a binary file. Then on the other server you can bulk insert this binary data back into a table of the same strucutre.

here's some code.

#### Export

```
Command Line: bcp "geodata.dbo.GeographyData" out "C:\GeoData.bin" -T -n -S <servername>
```

#### Notes

- This uses a Trusted connection
- use the bcp /? for more help for your export options if u need to be hardcore.

#### Importing the data

```
T-SQL: bulk insert GeographyData from 'C:\GeoData.bin' with (dataFileType='Native')
```

I learnt all this through the Spatial guru [Isaac Kunen](http://blogs.msdn.com/isaac/) and with the help of [Kent Tegels](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kent_tegels/), in this discussion thread [here](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4182363&SiteID=1).

The reason for the BCP method is highlighted by Isaac in this quote:

> Its worth pointing out that WKB is a
>   lossy format, in that it does not
>   store the SRID.  So if you extract and
>   insert the WKB, you'll have to carry
>   the SRID yourself.  Our internal
>   binary format does store the SRID, so
>   a BCP like this should be less hassle.

HTH.

EDIT: Replaced entire post question as a community wiki .. this this Post being an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally removed the question in the opening post, to replace it with the answer (at the end of '08) ... and make it a wiki.

So yeah .. the OP is the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

bulk insert error!!!
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":

Comment: dude -> we're using GEOGRAPHIES ... not geometries. make sure you've got your data type, right.