# How to bulk insert geography into a new sql server 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlgeography

I have a very large shape file with hundreds of thousands of rows of polygons and other associated data, like formatted addressing and APN numbers.  How do I get this data into a table with geography without using things like Shape2SQL?  I can't very well run an insert statement for every row that would take forever, the optimal solution would be to create a csv or a properly formatted bin file and then do a bulk insert, or `bcp`, or openrowset, but try, try, try as I might I cannot get a csv file or bin file to work.  Can anybody help?

The following code is the best I could manage.

```
SqlGeographyBuilder sql_geography_builder = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
sql_geography_builder.SetSrid(4326);
sql_geography_builder.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Polygon);
sql_geography_builder.BeginFigure(-84.576064, 39.414853);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576496, 39.414800);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576522, 39.414932);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576528, 39.414964);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576095, 39.415015);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576064, 39.414853);
sql_geography_builder.EndFigure();
sql_geography_builder.EndGeography();
SqlGeography sql_geography = new SqlGeography();
sql_geography = sql_geography_builder.ConstructedGeography;


FileStream file_stream = new FileStream("C:\\PROJECTS\\test.bin", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter binary_writer = new BinaryWriter(file_stream);

sql_geography.Write(binary_writer);
binary_writer.Flush();

binary_writer.Close();
file_stream.Close();
file_stream.Dispose();

SqlConnection sql_connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
sql_connection.Open();

SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand();
sql_command.Connection = sql_connection;
sql_command.CommandTimeout = 0;
sql_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sql_command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SPATIAL_TEST].[dbo].[Table_1] ([geo]) " +
              "SELECT [ors].* " +
              "FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\\PROJECTS\\AMP\\test.bin', SINGLE_BLOB) AS [ors] ";
sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql_command.Dispose();
sql_connection.Close();
sql_connection.Dispose();
```

But this only lets me import singularly the polygon--I need everything else as well.

Comment: csv files just plain dont work as ssis wont accept WFT or WFD as a valid field for bulk insert.  My only hope was to create a binary data file like seen here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282604/best-way-to-export-import-ms-sql-2008-geography-data) and the code above works great if all i want to do is just import the geography only.  Problem is that i have way more information to go into the file than just geography and i can't figure out how to build my binary file or my format file so i can do a proper bcp or openrowset.

Comment: For future readers, it is worth knowing that SqlBulkCopy in .NET can insert SqlGeoegraphy types directly. See this SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after several days of headache I have come to the conclusion that there is no answer.  Not even the mighty ESRI has any clue.  Thankfully I did come up with a different soultion.  In my table definition I created an NVARCHAR(MAX) column to hold the WFT of my geography and added that WFT to my csv file, and then after the bulk insert I run a table wide update statment to convert tht WFT to the actual geography type.  Also adjust the csv file to use a different character besides a , to separate with becuase the WFT contains ,'s

```
SqlGeographyBuilder sql_geography_builder = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
sql_geography_builder.SetSrid(4326);
sql_geography_builder.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Polygon);
sql_geography_builder.BeginFigure(-84.576064, 39.414853);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576496, 39.414800);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576522, 39.414932);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576528, 39.414964);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576095, 39.415015);
sql_geography_builder.AddLine(-84.576064, 39.414853);
sql_geography_builder.EndFigure();
sql_geography_builder.EndGeography();
SqlGeography sql_geography = new SqlGeography();
sql_geography = sql_geography_builder.ConstructedGeography;

StreamWriter stream_writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\PROJECTS\\AMP\\test.csv");
stream_writer.AutoFlush = true;
stream_writer.WriteLine("1?123 TEST AVE?" + sql_geography.ToString() + "?");
stream_writer.Flush();
stream_writer.WriteLine("2?456 TEST AVE?" + sql_geography.ToString() + "?");
stream_writer.Flush();
stream_writer.WriteLine("9?789 TEST AVE?" + sql_geography.ToString() + "?");
stream_writer.Flush();
stream_writer.Close();
stream_writer.Dispose();

SqlConnection sql_connection = new SqlConnection(STRING_SQL_CONNECTION);
sql_connection.Open();

SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand();
sql_command.Connection = sql_connection;
sql_command.CommandTimeout = 0;
sql_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sql_command.CommandText = "BULK INSERT [SPATIAL_TEST].[dbo].[Table_1] " +
                          "FROM 'C:\\PROJECTS\\AMP\\test.csv' " +
                          "WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '?', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n') " +
                          "" +
                          "UPDATE [SPATIAL_TEST].[dbo].[Table_1] " +
                          "SET [geo] = geography::STPolyFromText([geo_string], 4326) ";
sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql_command.Dispose();
sql_connection.Close();
sql_connection.Dispose();

MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```