# C# geography column in datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a datatable in C#, and I want to add a column to store latitude and longitude coordinates in a geography format to bulkcopy in SQL Server after that.

In what format should I create the datacolumn for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have to use the reference DLL that is located under
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll"*:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
```

After that, we can create the column in datatable, store some data and successfully send them to SQL Server via *bulkcopy*.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Geom", typeof(SqlGeometry));

DataRow newRow = datatable.NewRow();
newRow["Geom"] = SqlGeometry.Point(lat, lon, 4326);

datatable.Rows.Add(newRow);

SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MySpatialDataTable";
sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each column should be of a similar type to `Decimal(9,6)` where you have a length of `9` and a precision of `6`. Thus allowing for the maximum value could be `180°`

If you want to get really picky it actually could be.

Latitude: `Decimal(8,6)` (maximum of 90° to 0 north or south of the equator)

Longitude: `Decimal(9,6)` (maximum of 180° to -180°)

Decimal format in C#

`###.######`

If you were to combine them together, you will need to use a `nvarchar(25)` (it could be less than 25, but it leaves room for copy with formatting). As for the exact bulkcopy statement, you will need to provide a sample of the data.

Comment: Hi Nico! And how can I combine the two columns of Lat,Long to store it in sql geography column via bulkcopy?